# 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to start a React application locally but it fails to build, almost all components have the error **'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component**

[image: Error-react]

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@c4dwp/googleapi_core_library": "2.6.7",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.11",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.30",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.7",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.11.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.3",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/gapi.client.sheets": "^4.0.20201029",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/reactour": "^1.18.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.3",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.2",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.12",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.19",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.11",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.15",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "convert-array-to-csv": "^1.0.9",
    "convert-csv-to-array": "^1.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "csv-file-validator": "^1.7.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "detect-browser-language": "^0.0.2",
    "dexie": "^2.0.4",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "echarts": "^4.6.0",
    "echarts-for-react-typescript": "^1.2.5",
    "env-cmd": "^10.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "gapi-script": "^1.0.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^5.7.0",
    "google-spreadsheet": "^3.1.15",
    "googleapis": "^46.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "html-to-image": "^0.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "i18next": "^18.0.1",
    "json2csv": "^4.5.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-table": "^1.59.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "nocache": "^2.1.0",
    "objects-to-csv": "^1.3.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.0",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.8",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-data-grid": "^7.0.0-canary.16",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-file-drop": "^0.2.8",
    "react-file-reader": "^1.1.4",
    "react-fileupload": "^2.4.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.5",
    "react-google-picker": "^0.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.0.0",
    "react-intl-translations-manager": "^5.0.3",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-json-view": "^1.19.1",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.5",
    "react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-google-sign-in": "^1.0.16",
    "react-papaparse": "3.7.2",
    "react-redux": "7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-socket-io": "^0.2.5",
    "react-url-query": "^1.5.0",
    "react-user-guide": "^2.0.0",
    "reactour": "^1.18.1",
    "redux": "4.0.3",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "save-svg-as-png": "^1.4.14",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^4.0.0",
    "three-dots": "^0.2.0",
    "use-react-router": "^1.0.7",
    "use-state-with-callback": "^2.0.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.9",
    "@types/dexie": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/echarts": "^4.1.15",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "^0.0.51",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.2.3",
    "@types/i18n": "^0.8.6",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
    "@types/json2csv": "^4.5.1",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "12.7.11",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-file-reader-input": "^1.1.4",
    "@types/react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.18",
    "@types/react-table": "^6.8.5",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.31",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.44",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.14.0",
    "@types/why-did-you-update": "^0.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.8.0",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "fake-indexeddb": "^3.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-global": "^1.2.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.5",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.1",
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.4.0",
    "jest-sinon": "^1.0.2",
    "mocked-env": "^1.3.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "resolve": "1.12.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "start-server-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.5",
    "svg-url-loader": "2.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.14",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "why-did-you-update": "^1.0.6",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096&&webpack-dev-server --open --host localhost --config webpack.dev.js",
    "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' webpack-dev-server --open --host localhost --config webpack.dev.js",
    "dist": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "go": "webpack serve"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=5",
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/**/*.ts",
    "./public/css"
, "src/components/common/react-csv/src/components/Link.js"  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "build",
    "test",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The project is sitting in a yarn workspace.

What I have tried:

- Adding "resolutions/overrides" to the package.json file as it seems to fix the problem for other people online, but I keep getting the same error for almost all components
- Clearing yarn cache, deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, and doing a yarn install all over again.

It seems to be a configuration problem as the project is working well on other machines.

I get the errors when executing **yarn start:dev**

Help is appreciated as I've been blocked for several days!

Thank you

Comment: look at typescript and `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I have added the tsconfig.json file to the question